# .net native writing to file vs any logging framework

Tags: c#, .net, file, logging

are there any benefit of using log4net (or any other logging framework) vs just writing to file with native .net 
until now I used my utility class to write to file because I didn't know that such frameworks exits
so basically my question is there a point to ditch my class(which works fine for me) and convert to some logging framework
my class

```
class FileUtils
{

    string mPath;
    private static object locker = new Object();

    public void createNewLogFile(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                mPath = path;
                string backUpPath = path + @".bak";
                FileInfo MyFile = new FileInfo(path);


                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    if (new FileInfo(path).Length > Math.Pow(2, 20))
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(backUpPath))
                        {

                            File.Delete(backUpPath);
                        }
                        File.Copy(path, backUpPath);

                    }
                } 
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        //    outputFile.Close();
            var t = ex;
            throw;

        }
    }



    public void log (string fileLocation ,bool newLine, params  string[] input)
    {
        createNewLogFile(fileLocation);
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = File.AppendText(mPath))
        {
            outputFile.AutoFlush = true;

            try
            {
                if (newLine)
                    outputFile.Write(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss "));


                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                {
                     outputFile.Write(input[i] + "  ");                        
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                outputFile.Close();
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I am afraid, this is kind of opinion-based. Of course, Logging frameworks **do** have a lot of benefits: They are highly configurable (even during runtime). You don't have to reinvent the wheel. Output is not bound to file (you can log to windows event log, email, database, ... ) and they handle *a lot* of stuff for you so you can focus on your main task rather than how to do the logging.

Answer (score 0):

Logging for application is kind of CorssCutting consern. Log4NEt like library allows you to focus on business logic rather than focusing on logging part.

- Apart form that Log4Net allows you to log at different level, that is All,Info,warning, Debug etc.
- Log4NEt like library allows you to log your detail in File or in Database by simple configuration.

(There are also more features provided by framework like Log4Net, To achieve same feature lot of code required and you divert you attention from business logic to define framework for logging. )

If you have to achieve same functionality than you need to write lot of code (for different logging like to log in database one class and to allow log in file than other class) and lot of condition for differnet level.